# TortoiseHG is ignoring folder

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, hgignore

I added CKEditor to my project. After final configuration, I am not able to commit folder `dialog` in folder `ckeditor/plugins`. When I open TortoiseHG Workbench, there is no `dialog` folder to commit. Other users after update didn't get that folder, so editor not work for others.

I am not ignoring that folder. Here is my `.hgignore` file:
`syntax=regex
^\.
^target/
^jsTestDriver\.conf$
^node_modules/
^run-ft\.bat$
^run-ut\.bat$
log$
versionsBackup$
main\.css$
\.idea$
\.iml$`

When I rename folder `dialog` to something else (for example `dialog2`), it automatically appears and I can commit, but `dialog2` is useless for me. Please, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is normal, you have

```
log$
```

Which excludes the string if it ends with log, as in dia`log`...

If you need to exclude .log file, use

```
\.log$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `hg add` in console and add directory by hand (or move .hgignore temporary out of repository and add in GUI)

Try something like `hg add -I ckeditor/plugins/dialog/* -n` (and fix probably bad pattern for good result)